# An example of an endomorphism

Tags: modules

Could someone suggest a simple $\phi\in $End$_R(A)$ where $A$ is a ***finitely generated*** module over ring $R$ where $\phi$ is injective but not surjective? I have a hunch that it exists but I can't construct an explicit example. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have to exist for every ring and every module.

Comment: They also had a hunch back in Victor Hugo's time: it is to take $R=A=\mathbb Z$ and $\phi(z)=2z$.

Comment: I am very sorry, I have forgotten to include the condition that $A$ has to be finitely generated.

Comment: But Georges' $A$ is.

Comment: Don't worry, Teenager, it was quasi modo implicit.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks!

Comment: @ymar: indeed :) I just thought I should point out my edit

Comment: Dear @Georges: $+1$ for your mathematical comment, and $+$ the power of the continuum for your puns!

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves, thanks a lot: I really appreciate your kind comment.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R=K$ be a field, and let $A=K[x]$ be the polynomial ring in one variable over $K$ (with the module structure coming from multiplication). Then let $\phi(f)=xf$. It is injective, but has image $xK[x]\ne K[x]$.

Comment: Thank you! I am very sorry, I have forgotten to include the condition that $A$ has to be finitely generated.

Comment: No problem! I would have guessed that there wasn't one if $A$ was finitely generated, so thanks to Georges for setting me straight on that!

Comment: Dear Matt, +1 for your fine answer and even more  for your honest admission, which most wouldn't have made.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the morphism of $\mathbb{R}$-modules:

$$
\varphi : \mathbb{R}^\infty \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty
$$

defined by

$$
\varphi (x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n, \dots ) = (0, x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n , \dots ) \ .
$$

This example is not possible with finite dimension vector spaces, because then, with endomorphisms, you have

$$
\text{isomorphism} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \text{monomorphism} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \text{epimorphism} \ .
$$

EDIT. Now I see you've added the finitely generated condition. So, this example doesn't apply any more obviously.

Comment: Thank you, Agusti. I am very sorry about the edit.

Comment: Don't worry. But you've got your example in the comment by  Georges Elencwajg. (Maybe he should make it an answer, so you could chose as your accepted one.)

Comment: Dear Agustí: +1 since you perfectly answered the original question. And thanks but no, I won't write an answer. I only made the comment because I couldn't resist the temptation to make a pun in English (which isn't my mother tongue) !